# Aggregate & count "SELECT .... AS [Name]" field?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
Mid(Note, 
  InStr(Note, "device.")-
  (
   InStr(Note, "device.")-
   InStr(Note, "pressure and")
  )
  +13,
  (InStr(Note, "device.") - InStr(Note, "pressure and")) - 14
  )
  AS [Device],
  Count([Device]),
Date_Field & " " & Time_Field AS [DateTime],
EnteredBy
FROM MyLog
WHERE Note LIKE "*removed and*"
GROUP BY [Device]
ORDER BY Date_Field DESC
;
```

I would like to `GROUP BY` that custom field `[Device]` and count how many of each device there are. But the code above gives the error "... not include the specified expression ... as part of an aggregate function" for the "... AS [Device]" section.

How can I accomplish this?

Right now the data looks like:

```
Record1      12/05/12 03:02:12    User2
Record1      12/02/12 01:02:12    User1
Record1      12/01/12 02:02:12    User2
Record2      12/06/12 03:02:12    User2
Record2      12/07/12 03:02:12    User3
```

But I would like it to look like:

```
Record1    3
Record2    2
```

This is the old SQL that works (does not aggregate):

```
SELECT Mid(Note, 
  InStr(Note, "device.")-
  (
   InStr(Note, "device.")-
   InStr(Note, "pressure and")
  )
  +13,
  (InStr(Note, "device.") - InStr(Note, "pressure and")) - 14
  ) AS Device, Date_Field & " " & Time_Field AS [DateTime], EnteredBy
FROM MyLog
WHERE Note LIKE "*removed and*"
ORDER BY Date_Field DESC;
```

Comment: That is quite confusing. Your sample data does not include "pressure and" or "device" or "*removed and*". Have you any real sample data?

Comment: @Remou I cannot provide real data, no.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have a version that works. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to the alias device in a GROUP BY in MS Access, but you can create a subquery and refer to the alias from that.

This runs for me:

```
SELECT EnteredBy, Device, Count(Device) As CountDev FROM (
SELECT 
Mid(Note,InStr(Note,"device.")-
         (InStr(Note,"device.")-
          InStr(Note,"pressure and"))+13,
    (InStr(Note,"device.")-InStr(Note,"pressure and"))-14) AS Device, 
MyLog.EnteredBy
FROM MyLog
WHERE MyLog.[Note] Like "*removed and*")
GROUP BY EnteredBy, Device
```

Comment: Hmm my query normally worked before the GROUP BY stuff. When I try yours, it's saying "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function"

Comment: I'm now getting `...query that does not include the specified expression ... as part of an aggregate function.` where the expression is the `Mid(Note.....)` part. Also, I think I need to remove the Date/Time displays as those won't be aggregated.

Comment: Strange, getting "invalid procedure call" after your edit. If I remove those date/times (I don't need those aggregated), I still get that same `invalid length parameter` ODBC call failed.

Comment: Yes, your simple version works. I suspect it may be adding or subtracting and overflowing in some elements. Hmm.

Comment: You need to check that (InStr(Note,"device.")-InStr(Note,"pressure and"))-14 is > 0. Do you not have a list of possible devices as I suggested before? It really would be a lot easier.

Comment: I changed the `- 14` to `- 0` and still same error, must be something else. I'm trying to add some more WHERE statements to make sure it picks out the right rows. I might be able to compile a list, but again this is user input in the UI and they could typo things. :/

Comment: All the more reason for not tying this to such constraints. To troubleshoot, take your original ungrouped query and split out all those instr statements so you can see the numbers returned. If you can have typos, you can have them anywhere -- "presure ", so a list is much safer and more flexible. You can scan the rows that are *not* returned using the list and spot typos, these can be added to the list with a mapping to the correct name.

Comment: Actually "pressure" etc won't get typo'd, those are pre-defined dropdowns. Only the device gets typed in.

Comment: Give me the sentence that you are using with x's for any confidential words and q's or such like for variable data (device).

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that error because Device is not a column.  Perhaps you can use a subquery, although I admittedly haven't used Access in a while.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Count([Device]), Device, [DateTime], EnteredBy
FROM (
SELECT
Mid(Note, 
  InStr(Note, "device.")-
  (
   InStr(Note, "device.")-
   InStr(Note, "pressure and")
  )
  +13,
  (InStr(Note, "device.") - InStr(Note, "pressure and")) - 14
  )
  AS [Device],
  Date_Field & " " & Time_Field AS [DateTime],
  EnteredBy
FROM MyLog
WHERE Note LIKE "*removed and*" ) t
GROUP BY Device, [DateTime], EnteredBy
ORDER BY Date_Field DESC
;
```

Good luck.

Comment: I'm trying that and getting `Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function`. The substring works without the aggregate changes.

Answer (score 0):

something similar to this - basically nest the complex part into a subbquery.

```
select dev, count(dev) from
(
SELECT 
Mid(Note, 
  InStr(Note, "device.")-
  (
   InStr(Note, "device.")-
   InStr(Note, "pressure and")
  )
  +13,
  (InStr(Note, "device.") - InStr(Note, "pressure and")) - 14
  )
  AS dev,
Date_Field & " " & Time_Field AS DateTime,
EnteredBy
FROM MyLog
WHERE Note LIKE "*removed and*"
)
GROUP BY dev
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

Comment: Hmm that gives me `SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect`